# Is there a way to configure polling interval of @KafkaListener?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm new in the area of SpringBoot with Kafka. I saw that the common way to define a consumer is by `@KafkaListener`. 
In the psat I configure a scheduler which polling the Kafka broker every X time, but here I didn't found how to specified this interval or a documentation about pushing data from the broker to the consumer.
Is there a way to configure it ( or if the way of consuming data is by pushing I'll be happy to understand it)

Comment: `max.poll.interval.ms` is the max time to wait for records... The consumer has no such timer between poll requests, otherwise it's seen as inactive, and rebalances

Comment: @OneCricketeer check the answer, recent changes allow this behaviour just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was [recently introduced](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.html) into spring kafka, so if you are using modern version it should look like this:

**build.gradle**

```
implementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.6.1") // or higher, minimum required is 2.3.0
```

**Config.java**

```
@Bean("singleKafkaListenerContainerFactoryManualCommit")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> singleKafkaListenerContainerFactoryManualCommit(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setBatchListener(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(1000L); // <- this is basically it
    return factory;
}
```

How it's look like:

```
2020-11-27 17:04:41.099  INFO 67146 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.r.t.m.d.l.service.KafkaService    : Consumed message 
2020-11-27 17:04:42.143  INFO 67146 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.r.t.m.d.l.service.KafkaService    : Consumed message
2020-11-27 17:04:43.185  INFO 67146 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.r.t.m.d.l.service.KafkaService    : Consumed message
2020-11-27 17:04:44.223  INFO 67146 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] c.r.t.m.d.l.service.KafkaService    : Consumed message
```

**Keep in mind that you will need kafka broker version >= 1.0 to make it work.**

Comment: `idleBetweenPolls` was added in 2.3; it has no dependency on the broker version and will work with all recent brokers (>= 1.0). There is also no requirement for `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` ack mode.